# C code for finding all paths between two nodes in a given undirected graph

Tags: c

I want a C code for finding all the paths between two given nodes in an unweighted undirected graph covering all the vertices where vertices can be repeated but not edges

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service and "Gimme teh Codez" is Off-topic here.

Comment: Open your Data Structure book and start reading **Graph**.

Comment: Why not write code. I earn a living doing that

Answer (score 1):

Use Warshall's algorithm to solve the problem.